# How to keep cream soup warm for restaurant/cafe?

Tags: storage-method, food-science, soup, restaurant

I want to start a soup restaurant/cafe. And I want to keep my soup and cream soup (more thicker and creamy) warm or hot if it can. But I'm not sure how to do that. What is the equipment that I need to buy? And for how long my soup can last? Thank you!

Comment: I feel like there's a few things missing here. How *much* soup? What's a safe temperature to keep it at, and will the soup split? Also how often can you make new batches?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'd suggest consulting whatever food safety regulations are in force in your region for allowable temperatures/times/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will absolutely need to keep your soup at a safe temperature, unless your restaurant is located in an area with no health regulations and your business model doesn't consider making customers sick to be a negative.

Whether that's refrigerated or frozen and rapidly reheated for service or kept hot for long times will likely depend on the particular soup recipe. Some do well with long heating, some do not. Some don't freeze well. Local health regulations may also come into play, but quality of product will probably come into play first.

As for equipment, there are many options, from individual electrically heated pots to a large bain marie (water bath) with the water kept hot by whatever means and the items to be kept in it inserted into pots that fit into the water bath.